Opel/Vauxhall Zafira A - Cranks but won't start
first of all sorry English is not my first language and I'm not as knowledgeable with cars
I have a 2000 Opel/Vauxhall Zafira A 1.6 16V (101PS) which worked fine until yesterday. It doesn't want to start anymore. It cranks but it won't turn over. Video
Following information I already gathered:

car was starting fine the days before and on yesterday
Headlights, Radio, AC works (The Battery was changed 5 months ago)
During cranking rpm rises a bit - i think that means it's gets an engine speed signal
when i press on the gas pedal during cranking the rpm rises normaly but still won't start
I tried to see if I can hear the fuel pump working when I start the ignition - I heard a huming from the cockpit but nothing from the right side of the backseats

-> With this information I thought that there is in error in the fuel supplying system, but:

when I push the car it's starts and then shut downs again
when I stay on the gas pedal, after the pushing, I'm able to drive - but it's noticeable that the motor wants to shutdown and I was able to keep it runing giving thrust of gas pedal pushes
I was able to drive home like that (3min drive), motor stopped running when I also stopped
The engine light was on when I was driving, but no error lights while I was cranking

I don't know if I understood it correctly but the the car shouldn't be able to run if the fuel pump is bad, right?
I hope you can help me with this.
P.S. I could not read the error codes because I just had an OBD2 Scanner and my car doesn't have the right port (It looks like a OBD2 port but it's a proprietary Opel one)
